# What are the types of method parameters in data migrations?

Tags: django, django-migrations

When creating [data migrations with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), you create a function like `combine_names(apps, schema_editor)`.

What are the types of the parameters `apps` and `schema_editor` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The types are `django.db.migrations.state.StateApps` and `django.db.backends.postgresql.schema.DatabaseSchemaEditor`, respectively.

This makes the example method look like the following with type hints.

```py
# …
from django.db.backends.postgresql.schema import DatabaseSchemaEditor
from django.db.migrations.state import StateApps


def combine_names(apps: StateApps, schema_editor: DatabaseSchemaEditor):
    # …
```